# I am unable to update my state in Redux with dispatched action (using Redux-starter-kit)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I am very new to Redux *and* React-Native. I have a `state` which contains an array of `Expense` objects. One of the attributes is `comment`, which I am trying to update from a modal.

I think I have my code mostly right, but for some reason, the `state` is not updating with the newly updated item.

Modal Component code below:

```
 const expense = useSelector(state => state.expenses.model.find( expense => expense.id === expenseId ))

  const updateExpense = (updatedExpense) => dispatch(model.actions.updateExpense(updatedExpense))
  const addComment = () => {
    const updatedExpense = {
      ...expense,
      comment: "hi"
    }
    updateExpense (updatedExpense)
  }
```

Just to note,`index` is an attribute of the `expense` object.

and then here is where I set up my data `model` store and reducers:

```
    export const model = createSlice({
  slice: "model",
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {
    fetchSuccess: (state, { payload }) => (state = payload),
    updateExpense: (state, {payload}) => (
      console.log ("...State: ", state),
      console.log ("Payload", payload),
      state = [
        ...state.slice(0,payload.index),
       payload,
        ...state.slice (payload.index)
    ],
   /* state = {
...state, [payload.index]:{
  ...state[payload.index],
  comment: payload.comment*/
    console.log ("State: ", state)
    )
  }
});
```

My logs tell me that `payload` contains the correct information, its just not updating the `state`.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using `redux-starter-kit`, but you don't say you are or aren't. If you're not, ignore this answer.

Right now you're setting `state` in your reducer: `state` is a reference local to the reducer. You either need to modify a state *property*, or *return the new state*, [as described in the r-s-k docs](https://redux-starter-kit.js.org/api/createreducer#direct-state-mutation), e.g.,

```
updateExpense: (state, { payload }) => [
  ...state.slice(0, payload.index),
  payload,
  ...state.slice(payload.index)
]
```

Same goes for `fetchSuccess`.

Answer (score 0):

You should return the changed state your code it's not returning the state